# How to compile .C files in Eclipse using GCC

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, g++

I have a C project in Eclipse that compiles without any errors. But due to client requirements, I have renamed my source files into .C and .H, e.i, uppercase file extensions. But when I build my project, Eclipse shows:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project test_harness ****
Nothing to build for project test_harness
```

The logs show that GCC didn't recognized the files with uppercase extensions as C source files. Upon searching, I found out that the .C files are actually C++ files.

But is there a way to tell Eclipse to compile .C files using GCC instead of G++?

Comment: Can you show your makefile, I think it's more likely that there's something wrong in it.

Comment: And is your system Windows or Linux/Unix?

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl I have updated the question, it shows the actual output from Eclipse console. BTW, Eclipse didn't generate a Makefile after renaming the source files.

Comment: @MikeRobinson My system is Fedora Linux

Comment: ... hence, a case-*sensitive* file system.  I don't know if `.c` extensions will be recognized, if they are `.C` ...